# Extracation spatial features from one layer from geopakage file and applying to data file

Tags: geopackage

I have a GeoPackage file (OGC gpkg) which contains one main polygon layer representing forest stands with some unique keys.

The other layers are just tables and none of them are directly related to the polygon layer with unique key. 
It is possible to connect to connect the files by creating relations with multiple layers.

I have a chart containing the relation using PK and FK. 
I don't know how to extract the geometry of the polygons with the data I need.

Comment: Please share the chart showing how the data layers are related

Comment: Maybe it can be solved by joining two layers, then exporting the joined layer and then joining another layer to this new layer? It is difficult to tell without more information